# Combine SQL UNION and JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
query = "SELECT `receiver` as chat_users FROM inbox WHERE receiver='$my_id' or sender='$my_id' UNION SELECT `sender` FROM inbox'";
$run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
    $chat_user_id= $row['users'];
    query2 = "SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE receiver=$my_id AND sender=$chat_user_id UNION SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE receiver=$chat_user_id AND sender=$my_id LIMIT 1";
}
```

Explanation:
- this is related to chat system
 - 1st query return the unique list of chat user, the users who has done chating with me.
- in 2nd query i get the last message between me and the other chat user.

The queries are working perfect but i want to do it in better way, Is it possible to combine these 2 sql queries into 1?

Comment: Better than hard to decipher queries is:  (1) a description of what you want to accomplish; (2) sample results in a *text table* format in the question.

Comment: Possible, yes, it is very likely that they could be combined. But not from the limited information you have provided here. How do you want to combine them? What is the table structure and some sample data? How is the data related between the tables? etc.

Comment: That first query doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: i have modified the question for better understanding, please have a look

Comment: Your description of the first query isn't correct. It will return a list of inbox rows where the current user is either the sender or receiver, along with a full list of all senders because of the union select. The union in the 2nd query usn't needed. You can get the same result by using an order by that puts the most recent inbox row at the top of the results. That presumes an timestamp column in the table inbox. **Please edit your question and add the schema of the table inbox**.